# Validate user must install at least one of sub features

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

Here is the structure of my Application's Installer in FeatureTree/SelectionTree

**Application Core 

    |_ _ Feature 1 

    |_ _ Feature 2

    |_ _ Feature 3**

I want make sure that when user selects Application Core, he must select atleast one of Feature 1, Feature 2 or Feature 3.

I know Condition element under feature can be helpful, but was not able to get it working, Anyone at rescue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to validate the [ADDLOCAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367536(VS.85).aspx) property and disable the next until button  it has the "correct" value.
You can look at the EULA dialog for sample, the next button there is disabled until the user press the check box of agreeing to the EULA.

Comment: LicenseAgreementDlg is a built-in dialog provided by WixUIExtension.dll. How can you look at the dialog definition? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Not so convinced. If you can explain it with an example it would be great.

Comment: OK, I will try to create a sample.